# CipherSweet PHP Error when trying to encrypt zero(0) as the value

Tags: php, encryption

I'm using CipherSweet for server side data encryption with PHP. When I try to encrypt a variable with the value '0' I get an error.

The error I get is just an execution failure, no error message is thrown. I'm encapsulating the encryption line in a try catch block but `$e->getMessage()` returns blank.

The variable itself is encapsulated by `strval()` so the fact that the variable is an integer shouldn't matter, and I don't have any issue with encrypting other integers or any other vars, just 0 (but as a string).

I'm assuming that 0 is returning false in the cypher which is triggering an error, but as my variable is supposed to be changed to a string before encryption, I've no idea what's going on with it.

I have the cipher set up in a function; my code is otherwise as per CipherSweet documentation.

My code:

```
$var = 0;

$encVar = encryptFunc("encrypt", strval($var), "table", "column");
```

As stated before, the cipher only fails when the value of the variable to be encrypted is 0. It works as expected otherwise.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Result of `var_dump($e)`

```
file_path:208:
object(Exception)[8]
  protected 'message' => string '' (length=0)
  private 'string' => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'code' => int 0
  protected 'file' => string 'file_path' (length=62)
  protected 'line' => int 27
  private 'trace' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'file' => string 'file_path' (length=67)
          'line' => int 201
          'function' => string 'encryptFunc' (length=10)
          'args' => 
            array (size=4)
              ...
  private 'previous' => null
  public 'xdebug_message' => string '<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Exception:  in file_path on line <i>27</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th alig'... (length=1185)
```

EDIT 2:

After going through the result of the var_dump I noticed that in my cipher function that the error is being caused by the cipher reading '0' as an empty string.

Obviously the variable isn't empty, I know this error can be caused when the variable is passed as an integer, but I thought that converting the variable to a string should fix this issue.

EDIT 3:

Cryptograph Lib

```
<?php
    
    require_once "/srv/vendor/autoload.php";
    
    use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\Backend\ModernCrypto;
    use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\CipherSweet;
    use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\KeyProvider\StringProvider;
    use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\EncryptedField;
    use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\EncryptedRow;
    use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\BlindIndex;
    
    function encryptFunc($cryptType, $data, $table, $column, $blind = false, $blindColumn = "") {
        // Case Use 1: $string = encryptFunc("encrypt", "Some String", "users", "email")
        //             $string will contain encrypted string.
        // Case Use 2: list($encryptedString, $blindString) = encryptFunc("encrypt", "Some String", "users", "email", true, "email_idx")
        //             Use $encryptedString to store string. Store blindString to search.
        // Case Use 3: encryptFunc("decrypt", "EncryptedString", "users", "email") - blind not required
        
        if($cryptType !== "encrypt" && $cryptType !== "decrypt") {
            
            throw new Exception();
            
            return "Invalid Crypt Type";
            
        } else if(empty($data)) {
            
            throw new Exception();
            
            return "No data sent.";
            
        } else if(empty($table)) {
            
            throw new Exception();
            
            return "A table name must be provided.";
            
        } else if(empty($column)) {
            
            throw new Exception();
            
            return "A column name must be provided.";
            
        } else if(!is_bool($blind) && $blind !== true && $blind !== false) {
            
            throw new Exception();
            
            return "Invalid boolean value given.";
            
        } else if($blind && empty($blindColumn)) {
            
            throw new Exception();
            
            return "A blind column name must be provided.";
            
        }
        
        if($cryptType === "encrypt") {
            
            if(!file_exists("/srv/encKeys/enc.key") OR filesize("/srv/encKeys/enc.key") === 0) {
                $hex = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
                $provider = new StringProvider($hex);
                file_put_contents("/srv/encKeys/enc.key", $hex);
            } else {
                $provider = new StringProvider(file_get_contents("/srv/encKeys/enc.key"));
            }

            $engine = new CipherSweet($provider);
            
            if(!$blind) {
                
                $fieldEncrypter = (new EncryptedField($engine, $table, $column));
                
                $res = $fieldEncrypter->prepareForStorage($data);
                
                return $res[0];
                
            } else {
                
                $fieldEncrypter = (new EncryptedField($engine, $table, $column))
                ->addBlindIndex(
                    new BlindIndex(
                        $blindColumn, [], 32
                    )
                );
                
                list ($cipherText, $indexes) = $fieldEncrypter->prepareForStorage($data);
                
                return array($cipherText, $indexes[$blindColumn]);
                
            }
            
        } else if($cryptType === "decrypt") {
            
            if(!file_exists("/srv/encKeys/enc.key") OR filesize("/srv/encKeys/enc.key") === 0) {
                $hex = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
                $provider = new StringProvider($hex);
                file_put_contents("/srv/encKeys/enc.key", $hex);
            } else {
                $provider = new StringProvider(file_get_contents("/srv/encKeys/enc.key"));
            }

            $engine = new CipherSweet($provider);
            
            if(!$blind) {
                $fieldEncrypter = (new EncryptedField($engine, $table, $column));
            } else {
                $fieldEncrypter = (new EncryptedField($engine, $table, $column))
                ->addBlindIndex(
                    new BlindIndex(
                        $blindColumn, [], 32
                    )
                );
            }
            
            return $fieldEncrypter->decryptValue($data);
            
        }
        
    }
    
?>
```

Comment: I've also tried ````$var = "0"```` to no effect.

Comment: "an error" ? Please provide the exact error message...

Comment: @LarsStegelitz As I said in my post, there is no error message. ````$e->getMessage()```` returns as a blank string. All I get is a failed try catch block.

Comment: can you var_dump the exception $e?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz That's a good idea, thank you. I've edited my post with the result of the var_dump, though it doesn't really help me

Comment: After the ````var_dump()```` I've just delved through the function that contains the cipher again and noticed that the error is being thrown because the cipher is reading '0' as an empty string. Which offers a bit of insight but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Where is this `encryptFunc` function coming from exactly? Are you using [this library](https://github.com/paragonie/ciphersweet)?

Comment: @Jeto Yes, I'm using that library. I've put the cipher into its own function so that I can easily encrypt data when required. It's in its own little file that I include on every page where it's needed. It works as expected for the most part, but it seems to be reading '0' as an empty string.

Comment: @JustSomeGuy Please edit your question with the content of your function, just in case. It seems to be coming from the library itself, but it'll help figure out where it comes from.

Comment: @Jeto I've added the library.

Comment: Welp, there you go: `else if(empty($data)) { throw new Exception(); return "No data sent."; }`. [`'0'` is empty](https://www.php.net/empty). So it wasn't the library's fault after all :) You should pass your error message in the exception instead, as the `return` will never be reached (that's the point of throwing exceptions).

Comment: Uhm... throw Exception, but no message (thats why you dont get a message). After throw, the return is worthless because its never reached... add the string as argument to Exception and all is fine

Comment: @Jeto Noted, thank you. I'll add the error message. Now I know what the issue is, it still doesn't solve my problem though because I'm still getting an error. I've passed a string of "0" and it's reading it as empty, when it isn't. Having "0" is a crucial part of my application, so how do I get it to read "0" as a string, as opposed to as an empty string?

Comment: @JustSomeGuy Don't use `empty()` then. If you want to test for empty strings, simply compare with the empty string: `if ($data === '')`.

Comment: @Jeto Ah, okay. That's worked. Thank you. I'll add it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `empty()` to check for an empty string caused the library to read the string "0" as empty.

As per @Jeto's suggestion, I reverted to comparing the string with `if($data == "")` which solved the problem.

I also moved the error messages to the `throw new Exception()`, as opposed to `return`, so that they would appear when debugging.

Thanks for @Jeto and @LarsStegelitz for their help.